Geospatial segment data
I am trying to learn and implement uber system design. For this I wanted to match users and riders based on location. This got to me at a point where I would need geospatial data with segments.
I am new to this and was trying to find where I can get this data.
Are there any free apis which I can use to test this feature or I need to download them convert into coordinates and then do the mapping.
